# JDBCTemplate null when autowiring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

I know this has been asked many times before but the typical answer is if you create the object with new then Spring isn't aware of it and thus can not do the injection. In this scenario I cannot see why this would be the case as I am instantiating my class in Spring yet my call on JDBCTemplate is null.

What glaringly obvious mistake am I making here?

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO
{
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager manager;

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers()
    {
        List<User> users = template.query("SELECT * FROM USER", new UserRowMapper());
        return users;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addUser(User user)
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to add null user");
        }

        return true;
    }

}


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url"
            value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://...;integrated security=false" />
        <property name="username" value="..." />
        <property name="password" value="..." />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.rest.dao.UserDAOImpl" />
```

Comment: Where are you autowiring the `UserDAO`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either have to add the reference to the JdbcTemplate in the bean definition or add the tag `<context:annotation-config/>` in your XML configuration to enable the annotations.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

should help.